# Scaling a microservice with frontend and backend instances

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I am developing a series of microservices using Spring Boot and plan to deploy them on Kubernetes.

Some of the microservices are composed of an API which writes messages to a kafka queue and a listener which listens to the queue and performs the relevant actions (e.g. write to DB etc, construct messsages for onward processing).

These services work fine locally but I am planning to run multiple instances of the microservice on Kubernetes. I'm thinking of the following options:

1. Run multiple instances as is (i.e. each microservice serves as an API and a listener).
2. Introduce a FRONTEND, BACKEND environment variable. If the FRONTEND variable is true, do not configure the listener process. If the BACKEND variable is true, configure the listener process.
   This way I can start scale how may frontend / backend services I need and also have the benefit of shutting down the backend services without losing requests.

Any pointers, best practice or any other options would be much appreciated.

Comment: Standard practice here would be to have two separate images / deployments.  Also remember that you can't usefully have more listeners than Kafka topic partitions, which will limit your ability to scale the backends.

Comment: Thanks David, ideally I want one image but I will look into deployments and the partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as you describe, with environment variables, or you may also be interested in building your app with different profiles/bean configuration and make two different images.

In both cases, you should use two different Kubernetes [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) so you can scale and configure them independently.

You may also be interested in a [Leader Election pattern](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/) where you want only **one active replica** if it only make sense if one single replica processes the events from a queue. This can also be solved by only using a single replica depending on your *availability* requirements.

Comment: Great thanks Jonas. I will look into the leader election pattern. I think spring-cloud-kubernetes offers leader functionality as well.